# How to merge a value that is splitted in two rows and not create two seperate values in Python

Tags: python

I want to break the following text into 12 columns. This is a combined logfile from 4 other systems and is written in serial order. So I need all 12 values to be stored on each line. My problem is that on line 6-7 I have a value that starts on line 6 and ends on line 7 (24551). So far I handle them as two values but I want to handle it as one. Any suggestions?

11 0 555 962 299 33552 53 22233 5 0 0 4 16 0 746 1000 298 32781 219 21825 7 0 0
 4 10 0 619 1004 283 32579 23 21816 16 0 0 4 12 0 590 995 279 32451 42 21777 8 0
 0 4
 92 0 1474 2625 376 36329 51 24986 4 0 0 4 126 1 1683 2661 407 35434 215 24534 0
 0 0 4 118 5 1492 2604 392 35254 28 24528 1 0 0 4 102 0 1485 2603 395 35287 45 2
4551 1 0 0 4
 289 1 1445 3529 604 39883 48 28410 0 0 0 4 324 1 1634 3567 616 38698 217 27770 
0 0 0 4 310 12 1511 3617 605 38667 23 27836 0 0 0 4 313 3 1413 3604 575 38712 44
 27850 0 0 0 4

```
`import csv

with open('counters.txt','r') as csvfile, open('counters_modified.txt','w',newline="") as file1:  # newline="" to avoid blanks
    stripped = (row.lstrip() for row in csvfile)  
    reader = csv.reader(stripped,delimiter=' ')
    writer= csv.writer(csvfile1)
    writer.writerows(reader)   

with open("counters_modiied.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=","))
flat_list = []
for sublist in lines:
    for item in sublist:
        flat_list.append(item)

n = 12

final = [flat_list[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(flat_list) + n - 1) // n)]
print(final)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was that pycharm auto delete the last space from my rows.